# Run mongo index command from terminal, solutions for a very large index

Tags: mongodb

I'm trying to enable full text search on my mongo instance, but the collection I'm indexing is quite large.  Normally, I'd open up the mongo console and type:

```
db.articles.ensureIndex({"text":"text"})
```

However, I've waited an hour and would like to run this overnight, so I'm seeking the ability to run something like a `nohup` command.

I am aware I can do some things like:

```
mongo dbname --eval "db.articles.ensureIndex({'text':'text'})"
```

But even rephrasing this as:

```
nohup mongo dbname --eval "db.articles.ensureIndex({'text':'text'})" &
```

This is still totally blocking my mongo usage.  That is,

```
$ mongo
> show dbs
```

Times out while the other job is running in the background---completely unusable while indexing.  Is there any way to run this more effectively as a background process, or limit the index command to only so many threads or something?

**UPDATE**
Actually, it's worse than that.  Running this index command seems to have my mongo blocked and hobbled entirely.  Very, very big index, I assume.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use the `background` option.

```
db.collection.ensureIndex({ text: 'text', background: true })
```

From mongodb's documentation:

> Builds the index in the background so that building an index does not
>   block other database activities.

More information here http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.ensureIndex/